# Vaadin addon ICEpush Error during maven install

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, icepush

I am trying to use Vaadin Addon ICEpush. I have added the following maven snippet to my pom.xml

```
<!-- vaadin icepush add-ons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>icepush</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icepush</groupId>
        <artifactId>icepush</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-Beta1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have also added the following to pom.xml

```
<repository>
        <id>ICEFaces</id>
        <url>http://anonsvn.icefaces.org/repo/maven2/snapshots/</url>
</repository>
```

But when I maven install from eclipse I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1:compile 
(default-cli) on project sudo: GWT Module org.icepush.gwt.ICEpush not found 
in project sources or resources. -> [Help 1]
```

any suggestions on how to solve this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Since Vaadin 7.1 is released, you get the push function from the framework(@Push Annotation). 
See [here](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Enabling%20server%20push). 
This mean you dont need the plugin ICEPush anymore.

If you want implement ICEPush for a Vaadin version below 7.1, you should take a look on this [site](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/icepush).
 
The Maven Implementation should looks like this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
   <artifactId>icepush</artifactId>
   <version>0.5.5</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
   <id>vaadin-addons</id>
   <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
</repository>
```

And you have to add to your web.xml file the following lines

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ICEPush for Portlets</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.vaadin.artur.icepush.ICEPushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ICEPush for Portlets</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```